# React: what happens to a function when component stop being rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a function defined in a component, it start and keeps running when the component is mounted. What happens to the function when the component stops being rendered or dismount?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<> {
  _count = () => {
    console.log('a second passed');
    setTimeout(1000, this._count);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    _count();
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing. The function keeps running and scheduling itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timer will keep running unless it gets cleared, so you will want to clear it in [`componentWillUnmount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) which is used to "perform any necessary cleanup...such as invalidating timers":

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  _count = () => {
    console.log('a second passed');
    this.countTimer = setTimeout(this._count, 1000);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    _count();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.countTimer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!